# "All else equal"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Looking for a way to articulate "holding all else equal." In my context, I'm writing about economists' (unrealistic) love for holding all else equal

Comment: The more common expression is *everything being equal*. (Although it's not clear if it would be a suitable replacement, since it might have a different meaning.) Can you provide an actual sentence or two for context? If you need a single word specifically, can I ask why? (What's wrong with the phrase you already have?)

Answer (score 2):

Economists like to use the Latin phrase:

[ceteris paribus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus) - other things equal.

https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/definition/ceteris-paribus

Comment: You need to source you citations, not just link them.